# How to design notification system that sends real-time alerts created by users

Tags: events, design-patterns, event-handling, system-design

I've been thinking about how to design a system that supports user created scheduled alerts. My problem is once the alerts are created and inserted into a database, I don't know what the best way to go about scheduling those alerts. Polling the database to see which alerts need to go out next doesn't seem entirely right to me.

What are some ways this could be handled on a scale where say a million users could create their own custom alerts like change baby diaper at 3pm everyday?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is very suitable for cloud platforms. For example, you could use GCP Cloud Scheduler to invoke a cloud function when the alert is supposed to be sent out. The cloud function then calls some API to alert the user.

If cloud platforms are not an option, you could have your application spawn a new thread when an alert is created, and sleep that thread for a certain duration. When it wakes up, it sends the alert. Less elegant and less scalable than the first solution, but it would still work.

Comment: Regarding the first option, how would the GCP Cloud Scheduler know when to send out notifications if we had a database with 5 million active custom notification schedules all with varying levels of granularity to when it needs to go out?

Comment: For each notification schedule, you would create a cron job on Cloud Scheduler. You can specify the frequency at which the job runs. This doc may be helpful https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating

Comment: Thank you for response Tyler, I do appreciate it. However I can't see this scaling out appropriately if each user could have multiple scheduled notifications and each one has their own CRON job associated with it. This table containing the notification schedules could grow to over hundreds of millions. An example average use case is for a daycare app. In the daycare app the notification feature is just a small subset of the app, but each user can schedule their own notifications like feed baby at 12pm, change diapers every 2 hours, call baby's parent at 10am, etc.

Comment: Cloud Scheduler is a fully managed service, you don't need to worry about scaling it. The default quota for jobs is 5000 per project, but you can request an increase. There's nothing stopping you from creating millions of jobs, if that's what your use case demands. https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/quotas